# Wamp Server not starting in Windows 10 64-bit

Tags: php, mysql, apache, server, wampserver

I was writing some PHP code for my web application recently. I was trying to test sending an e-mail from a contact form on a local server (by using a variety of methods, including SendMail). None of them worked (though it may be code-related but I don't know yet). I basically restarted Apache/MySQL several times throughout testing. At one point when I was changing the configurations for SendMail, I was unable to re-start Apache & MySQL after stopping them. The icon remained red. Every time I try to start Apache, nothing would happen and the icon still remains red. I tried doing it manually from Services but it's giving me an error. It has always worked in the past, so I am not sure what's happening now or whether or not changing some of the SMTP configurations on php.ini or sendmail.ini and installing these mail server tools messed something up?

Anyone have any suggestions on how to fix/troubleshoot this? I am pretty new to server-side development. I appreciate the help!

Comment: 1) undo your last change to any of the config files. 2) look in the logs `C:\wamp\logs` 3) look in the Windows Event Viewer for error messages from APache and/or MySQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be a hundred different things, do what welshGaz said and check your logs.  If you're still stuck after that, you have the following options:

1. Uninstall/Reinstall WAMP
2. Try an alternative to WAMP such as XAMPP
3. Spin up a virtual environment using virtual box and ubuntu
4. Spin up a server on Amazon Web Services, Heroku, etc.

These are options are of the last-resort variety, but if you're in a pinch and don't have time to troubleshoot, one of these options might be a faster way to get back up and running.

Comment: 1) A great big Sledge hammer to crack a nut

Comment: OP admits to fiddling with config. So 1) is undo last change

Comment: Haha, seemingly yes.  BUT, we don't know that the config is the issue for sure.  The OP could have easily fat-fingered, deleted, copy/pasted bad info, etc.  I'd hate for the OP to fret over the config when it might not possibly be the issue, so here are some other options.

Comment: I ended up uninstalling WAMP and reinstalled XAMPP. It's way easier to use and set up in general, and it's got a mail server along with it too. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I think the first place to go would be the WAMP logs. On Windows these can be found under the root_application_install_directory/logs. For example on my Windows 10 machine I can find them under C:\wamp64\logs.

You should find all logs from Apache, PHP etc. placed here. Having a look at those may help you get closer to the cause of your issue and why the server is not starting.